# Confused about if there's any difference among these sentences

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, grammaticality

Let's look at some sentences:

**1. There is water in the bottle**.

**2. The bottle has water in it**.

**3. Water is in the bottle**.

Do these three sentences mean same? If they mean different, then what is the meaning of each sentence and how do they differ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They all mean the same thing. The only difference is that native English speakers would only use the first one in natural speech. And maybe the second one. But very rarely would anyone use the third version unless someone asked the exact question:

> Where is the water?

And even then the response would be

> *The* water is in the bottle.

Comment: To me the second one suggests something like "There is wine in the jug but if you don't want an alcoholic drink, the bottle has water in it."

Comment: Oh my gosh, that's true. Good point.